# How to use Keras ImageDataGenerator for image transformation inputs

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I'm attempting to train a model which transforms an image into another image (so, not an image classification problem). It is Auto Colorization, i.e transforming grayscale images to color.

I have modeled my sequential DL model.

I want to provide (image_x, image_y) and not (image_x, label) as inputs to the model.fit() method.

How can I use ImageDataGenerator to do that?

If ImageDataGenerator is not the appropriate method, can you please refer me to the appropriate Keras method which can do the job?

I have the images in directories

- `train/grayscale/`
- `train/color/`
- `validation/grayscale`
- `validation/color`
- `test/grayscale`
- `test/color`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is like an image segmentation task. There is an example of transforming images and masks (in your case color images) together with ImageDataGenerator in [keras documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

Here is the example:

```py
# we create two instances with the same arguments
data_gen_args = dict(featurewise_center=True,
                     featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                     rotation_range=90.,
                     width_shift_range=0.1,
                     height_shift_range=0.1,
                     zoom_range=0.2)
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

# Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the fit and flow methods
seed = 1
image_datagen.fit(images, augment=True, seed=seed)
mask_datagen.fit(masks, augment=True, seed=seed)

image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/images',
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)

mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/masks',
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)

# combine generators into one which yields image and masks
train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2000,
    epochs=50)
```

> Please note that in case of class_mode=None, the data still needs to
>   reside in a subdirectory of directory for it to work correctly.

For example, when you are passing `train/grayscale` and `train/color` to two `flow_from_directory` functions, the directory of train images should be like this:

- `train/grayscale/images`
- `train/color/images`

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. I have looked at the documentation. 
All that I can see is that if I place images in data/folder1 and data/folder2, ImageDataGenerator will generate batches with labels folder1 and folder2. 
I don't see how I can tell it to grab (x_train, y_train) where y_train is an image and not a label.

Comment: I've edited my answer and add the example and some notes. I hope this will help you.

Comment: @Matin - I just don't understand something. At image_dagen.fit() you've to provide a variable *images*... what are these?  because in the image_generator, you're already specifying your images...

Comment: @Dieter - If you want to use for example featurewise normalization in ImageDataGenerator, first you need to compute mean and std on a bunch of data. Usually this data is the whole training data but you can also use something else.